# Consuming WSE Web Service using Dynamic Port in BizTalk 2013

Tags: biztalk, wse, biztalk-2013

We have an application currently running in BizTalk 2006 R2 sending message to WSE2.0 web service using a dynamic send port. The properties it set for soap message port are as follow:

```
Message(WSE.IntegrityUser) = "some user"
Message(WSE.IntegrityPassword) = "Plain text Password"
Message(WSE.IntegrityPasswordOption) = "Plain text option"
Message(WSE.SoapAction) = "Operation Name"
Message(WSE.AuthenticationScheme) = "Integrated"
```

and the address for Dynamic port is set as below:

```
DynamicPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = URL
```

Now I want to upgrade this solution to BizTalk 2013 and found that it no more support WSE. What are the alternatives to keep using Dynamic port?

Comment: Have you looked at WCF-BasicHttp?  Have a look at this blog  http://fafach.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/biztalk-2010-converting-wse-send-port-to-wcf/  It is not a Dynamic one, but there should be some useful info in it regardless.

Comment: Yes I have already gone through it, but my problem is I can't use static ports. I don't have static username, i have to pass it in soap message at runtime because I also received it from somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a msdn doc that you can reference to configure your dynamic port in BT with WCF adapters.There is sample code as well.

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727706.aspx)